# Is it possible to capture the connection string used to connect to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string, sql-server-2019

I have recently taken over a number of [SQL Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) databases that are configured with mirroring. I understand there are some applications that connect using the "Failover Partner" option in the connection string.

Because I want to migrate the databases to SQL Server 2019 with *[Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/getting-started-with-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server)* (AGs), I'd like to identify these applications so that I can get the connection strings changed.

I am not adverse to doing the migration and initially implementing a two-node AG without any readable secondaries if the only tools available to capture this exist in later versions of SQL Server, but my ultimate goal is to have multiple AGs based on [RTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_recovery#Recovery_Time_Objective) for the database.

If it is not possible to capture the string or the "Failover Partner" property, another option would be to try and capture any connections that are using SQL Server Native Client.

Comment: From within the database engine? No

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea too; connection strings can contain usernames and passwords and those should not be exposed easily.

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_connections` and `sys.dm_exec_sessions` basically represent all that's available to you with regards to connection information, with the `endpoint_id` and `sys.endpoints` possibly of use to you (not tested), or at least `client_interface_name`.

Comment: [dup on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/311939/is-it-possible-to-capture-the-connection-string-used-to-connect-to-sql-server)